# Basic jsPDF Implementation

Tags: javascript, pdf, jspdf

Using jsPDF, currently attempting to do the following:

1. Define downloadPDF function

   - Generate PDF document with "Hello world" string
   - Download PDF document
2. Declare a button with an onclick that calls downloadPDF()

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//mrrio.github.io/jsPDF/dist/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    function downloadPDF() {
      var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'in', 'letter');
      doc.text('Hello world', 10, 10);
      doc.save('myPDF');
    }
  </script>
  <button onclick="downloadPDF()" class="button">Run Code</button>
</body>

</html>
```

But the PDF document turns out to be empty.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Did you not add a page first, as [in a random example found with Google](http://mrrio.github.io/jsPDF/examples/basic.html)?

Comment: Calling add page adds a second page. As soon as you input text, the first page is automatically generated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are the arguments that you're passing to the jsPDF constructor supposed to do? Removing them worked for me:

```
var doc = new jsPDF();
```

Working example: http://output.jsbin.com/kaxafuwiri

Comment: jsPDF(orientation, unit, format)
Creates new jsPDF document object instance. That's what the API says it's supposed to do. Is this a bug or are the docs simply misleading?

Comment: I would not trust documentation that is almost three years old ... "Documentation generated by JsDoc Toolkit 2.4.0 on Mon Oct 15 2012 22:41:49 GMT-0700 (PDT)"

Comment: The 10, 10 coordinate, with those document properties, seems to place the text off the page.